# Как вывести URL в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt5, qlabel

Какую ***View*** нужно использовать и как это реализовывается в *Python*?
Я пытался сделать так:

```
self.ui.webView.addItem(QUrl(link))
```

Но ничего не вышло, такого метода нет у `webView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не уверен, что понял в чем у вас проблема, но попробуйте пример：

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.label = QLabel('<a href="https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#openExternalLinks-prop"> doc.qt.io </a>')

        # openExternalLinks - Указывает, должен ли QLabel автоматически открывать 
        # ссылки с помощью QDesktopServices.openUrl() 
        # вместо того, чтобы излучать сигнал QLabel.linkActivated().
        self.label.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("Как вывести URL в PyQt5")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

#        self.label = QLabel('<a href="https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#openExternalLinks-prop"> doc.qt.io </a>')

        self.label = QLabel('''<h3>Какой-то список ссылок:</h3> 
        <br><br>
        <a href="https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#openExternalLinks-prop"> doc.qt.io </a> <br>
        <a href="https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html"> <b>QLabel Class</b> </a> <br>
        <a href="https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel-members.html"> List of All Members for QLabel </a> <br>
        ''')


        # openExternalLinks - Указывает, должен ли QLabel автоматически открывать 
        # ссылки с помощью QDesktopServices.openUrl() 
        # вместо того, чтобы излучать сигнал QLabel.linkActivated().
        self.label.setOpenExternalLinks(True)

        self.grid = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.label)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.setWindowTitle("Как вывести URL в PyQt5")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну это почти то, а если я хочу вывести список ссылок?

Comment: @ОлегСветовидов я добавил пример со списком ссылок, пробуйте

Comment: Спасибо, большое!